# How to compose an OR query for a singular where clause, that doesn't affect the rest of the query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm looking to write a query that utilizes an OR statement within a where clause, but only ONE where clause:

Take this query for example:

```
      Job
      .joins(:quote)
      .joins(:revisions)
      .where.not(revisions: {approved_date: nil})
      .where(billed_date: nil)
      .where(art_billed_date: nil)
      .where.not(quote: {approval_date: nil})
      .or(Job.where(company_id: [companies_to_display]))
```

and the problem comes with the last two chains

```
      .where.not(quote: {approval_date: nil})
      .or(Job.where(company_id: [companies_to_display]))
```

These are meant to be used together, and sort of depend on one another.  What I want for this is to **Only look for the companies to display IF the quote.approval_date is NIL**

How do I do this with Rails 7 utilizing OR?

Comment: What is `Object` here? It seems this is key to the question and could drastically simplify the implementation. Right now I have no idea how `Job` relates to this query or to `Quote` if at all.

Comment: @engineersmnky Object is Job, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
      Job
      .left_joins(:quote)
      .left_joins(:revisions)
      .where.not(revisions: {approved_date: nil})
      .where(billed_date: nil)
      .where(art_billed_date: nil)
      .where.not(quote: {approval_date: nil})
      .or(Job.where(company_id: [companies_to_display]))
      .distinct
```

I think this will do it.  You want all Jobs - even those without quotes (left_join) and then qualify the results on not(quote: {approval_date: nil}) or company_id: [companies_to_display].

Comment: I plugged this query into my application and the data was not as expected.  Perhaps this situation is a little to dynamic for people with no context to solve.  Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the `.scoping` method.

```
   Job
    .joins(:quote)
    .where.not(revisions: {approved_date: nil})
    .where(billed_date: nil)
    .where(art_billed_date: nil)
    .scoping do
        Job
        .joins(:quote)
        .where.not(quote: {approval_date: nil})
        .or(Job.where(company_id: companies_to_display))
     end
```

The only downside is that I'm pretty much building three queries here instead of two.  See the duplicated join/custom include statements.  As for my application, the records it will spit out will never get that large as they are actively maintained, but it would be a problem if there was a large amount of records.

Any refactoring advice is appreciated!